# Beautiful Soup 4 Python 3.6.5 web scraping for real time currency conversion from GBP to USD

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a web page for the conversion rate of GBP to USD from this site https://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=GBP&to=USD&amount=1.

I've identified the class for the conversion rate in the HTML of the link above as "ccOutputRslt" however when printing what is scraped what is returned to me reads:

```html
<span class="ccOutputRslt">1.338<span class="ccOutputTrail">241</span><span class="ccOutputCode"> USD</s
pan></span>
```

How does one go about removing the  tags from the code, as well as removing the string "USD" contained in class="ccOutputCode" so that what's printed will be the float "1.338241", so the conversion can take place.

here is the python code for my file:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=GBP&to=USD&amount=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price_box = soup.find(class_="ccOutputRslt")
rate = price_box
print(rate) #checking the output

def gbp_to_usd(rate,gbp):
    dollars=gpb*rate
    return dollars
gbp = input("Enter GBP amount: ")
finalamt = gbp_to_usd(float(rate),float(gbp))
print(str(gbp)+" GBP is equvalent to "+"$"+str(finalamt)+" USD")
```

I'm still very new to python and coding in general, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Chris

Comment: If you read their FAQ, it asks that you "Please do not attempt to automate the process of rate data collection or harvesting from our site." It looks like you doing so puts them in violation of their agreement with the upstream data provider. So if you're lucky they'll write the code to detect and shut down your scraper; if you're unlucky whoever they're buying the data from will cut off their data.

Comment: @abarnert Aw, well that sucks, I don't intend on keeping the scraper running 24/7 i'm just trying to practice some python :( could someone still help me out for future references

Comment: For a quick-and-dirty answer, assuming you have the outer span in a variable named `span`, you probably just want to iterate over [`span.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings), which should give you `1.338`, then `241`, then `USD`.

Comment: For a cleaner answer, you want to find the subtags by class. For example, `span.find('span', class_='ccOutputTrail').text` will give you `241`. The best way to understand what this means is to start at [Kinds of filters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) and read through the part about CSS classes. But since you've already written code that does this to find the outermost box, you should understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should get you the desired value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=GBP&to=USD&amount=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

part1 = soup.find(class_="ccOutputTrail").previous_sibling
part2 = soup.find(class_="ccOutputTrail").get_text(strip=True)
rate = "{}{}".format(part1,part2)

def gbp_to_usd(rate,gbp):
    dollars=gbp*rate
    return dollars

gbp = input("Enter GBP amount: ")
finalamt = gbp_to_usd(float(rate),float(gbp))
print(str(gbp)+" GBP is equvalent to "+"$"+str(finalamt)+" USD")
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much SIM, this works perfectly! I'm curious as to how what you've added works in order to further my knowledge. 

So from what i'm trying to gather, the .previous_sibling will save the value of the previous class called before it into the part1 variable.

The .get_textgets the text within the class "ccOutputTrail" and the (strip=True) removes the white space around it.

Then you set the rate variable equal to separate empty dictionaries and formatted the position of the variables in the proper order. does that sound correct? Thanks again so much for the help SIM.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you want

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=GBP&to=USD&amount=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price_box = soup.find('span',{'class':'ccOutputRslt'})
rate = price_box.text.replace("USD", ' ')

def gbp_to_usd(rate,gbp):
    dollars=gbp*rate
    return dollars


gbp = input("Enter GBP amount: ")
finalamt = gbp_to_usd(float(rate),float(gbp))
print(str(gbp)+" GBP is equvalent to "+"$"+str(finalamt)+" USD")
```